# How to define multiple modules sharing same data bus in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to understand how pins should be defined in SystemVerilog.

I have:

- a common `dataBus`
- a `ramController` module which can send or receive data on its `ioData` pins.
- a top level module which can write to the `ramController` (e.g. prepare a display buffer)
- a `vgaController` which mostly receives data from the `ramController` but also has a command mode which allows it to be configured using data on the `dataBus`

The `ioData` pins in the `ramController` are bi-directional but also need to be tri-state so that the `ramController` can be "off the bus" when `dataBus` is being used to send commands to the `vgaController`

```
module RAMController(
    inout wire[15 : 0 ] ioData,
    ..
);
..
    logic [15 : 0 ] ioDataCopy;
    assign ioData = ( chipSelect ) ? ioDataCopy : 16'hzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz;
```

Even if vgaController never writes to the dataBus, does it's pins need to be inout in order to be input or HiZ?

```
module VGAController(
    inout  wire  [15 : 0 ] iData;
);
..
logic [15 : 0 ] iDataCopy    = 0;
assign iData = ( chipSelect ) ? iDataCopy : 16'bzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz;
```

Is `dataBus` simply a set of wire values in the top module?

```
module Top(
..
);
..
wire   [15 : 0 ] dataBus;
```

I may be going about this completely wrong. Can someone please help me in defining a system containing multiple modules that share the same bus.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say if you did it right or wrong without a reproducible example. However, some of your assertions are basically correct. I assume that your `dataBus` is same as your `ioData` at the controller level. In this case if both controllers are instantiated in 'top' and are connected correctly, you should be all set. You have to make sure that there is always only a single driver for the bus, so that 'chipSelect' prevents from multiple driving of the bus.

So, here is an example that demonstrates the above.

```
module Top();
  wire   [15 : 0 ] dataBus;
  logic[1:0] select;
  
  RAMController rc(.ioData(dataBus), .chipSelect(select == 1 ? 1 : 0));
  VGAController vc(.ioData(dataBus), .chipSelect(select == 2 ? 1 : 0));
  
  always @*
    $display("%0t select: %b, data: %b", $time, select, dataBus);
  
  initial begin
    select = 0;
    #1 select = 1;
    #1 select = 0;
    #1 select = 2;
    #1 select = 0;
    #1 $finish;
  end
  
endmodule

module RAMController(
    inout wire[15 : 0 ] ioData,
    input logic chipSelect 
    //...
);
  logic [15 : 0 ] ioDataCopy = 1;
  assign ioData = ( chipSelect ) ? ioDataCopy : 'z;
endmodule

module VGAController(
    inout wire[15 : 0 ] ioData,
    input logic chipSelect 
    //...
);
  logic [15 : 0 ] ioDataCopy = 2;
  assign ioData = ( chipSelect ) ? ioDataCopy : 'z;
endmodule
```

and the result:

```
0 select: 00, data: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
0 select: 00, data: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
1 select: 01, data: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
1 select: 01, data: 0000000000000001
2 select: 00, data: 0000000000000001
2 select: 00, data: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
3 select: 10, data: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
3 select: 10, data: 0000000000000010
4 select: 00, data: 0000000000000010
4 select: 00, data: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

To be more verbose you could use `tri` definition instead of `wire`. There is no difference between them, but makes the code more readable, IMHO.

```
tri [15:0] dataBus;
...
tri [15:0] ioData;
```

Comment: Thankyou @Serge. I will try and dumb down my project and possibly update my question. I'm getting ""Top" must drive a to-level pin but is driving <nothing>" now. It's hard finding time to focus on this outside of work too :-( I definitely prefer the tri definition though - that is a lot clearer.